# How to test RESTful web services under UI using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, rest, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured, jersey-test-framework

I am using selenium webdriver for UI test automation, while testing UI automation i want to test the webservices which are used by UI to load data. how to do this using selenium webdriver. i am using java with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is limited to UI automation. However you can use other testing frameworks such as:

1. **REST-Assured**: https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured

   BDD Styled fluent-interface for verifying REST services.

   Quick Tutorial on Rest-Assured: http://www.hascode.com/2011/10/testing-restful-web-services-made-easy-using-the-rest-assured-framework/
2. **Jersey-Test-Framework**: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html

   Comparison of Rest-Assured & Jersey-Test-Framework: http://www.hascode.com/2011/09/rest-assured-vs-jersey-test-framework-testing-your-restful-web-services/